# How do I address a custom tag?

Tags: jquery, tags

I understand that I can address a ID or a class such as:

```
<img id="htmlTag">
```

with

```
$("#htmlTag").function();
```

or

```
<img class="htmlTag">
```

with

```
$(".htmlTag").function();
```

... but how do I address this:

```
<img caption="htmlTag">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You an take advantage of jQuery's [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), like so:

`$("img[caption='htmlTag']");`

Answer (score 3):

You want this:

```
$('img[caption="htmlTag"]')
```